# Django Template Hide Microseconds from Timedelta

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is there a filter I can apply in a Django template so that I only display "hh:mm:ss" for a timedelta, even if it has microseconds? I just want to not show the microseconds component. The "time" filter doesn't seem to work for timedelta.

Right now I am doing this before sending to the template, but I have thousands of rows and it seems "expensive":

```
mytimedelta = mytimedelta - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=mytimedelta.microseconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thousands of rows is not that bad, plus I'm not aware of any django builtin function to achieve this. Even if it has one, it might as well does the same thing as you currently have. The best you can do is to create a custom django template filter to do it, it might make your life a little easier.